# which is the best or widely used MVVM Toolkit for WPF?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

Could you tell me which is the best MVVM pattern someone have to follow (like Prism). Where can I find hands-on examples to help? Actually, I am little confused which one to follow?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Wikepedia article about MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) has a list of frameworks. Here is a selection of some of the frameworks from the list:

- [Calcium](http://www.calciumsdk.net/)
- [Caliburn](http://www.caliburnproject.org/)
- [Cinch](http://cinch.codeplex.com/)
- [CoreMVVM](http://coremvvm.codeplex.com/)
- [MVVM Foundation](http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com/)
- [MVVM Light Toolkit](http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/)
- [WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com/)
- [WPF Model-View-ViewModel Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WPF%20Model-View-ViewModel%20Toolkit&referringTitle=Home)

Personally, I can recommend Rob Eisenberg's Caliburn. You can see his very educating introduction to MVVM at MIX 2010: [Build Your Own MVVM Framework](http://live.visitmix.com/MIX10/Sessions/EX15).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you are exactly mean. MVVM itself is a design pattern. if you mean what are MVVM's best implementations and libraries then some of them are as follow:

- WPF MVVM Toolkit: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140506031031/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ivo_manolov/archive/2009/05/03/9584900.aspx)
- Prism
- Cinch: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180118124108/http://cinch.codeplex.com:80/)
- MVVM Foundation: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180107163950/http://mvvmfoundation.codeplex.com:80/)
- MVVM Light: [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20180703215243/http://www.galasoft.ch:80/mvvm/getstarted/)

also [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2009/february/patterns-wpf-apps-with-the-model-view-viewmodel-design-pattern) you can find a great article about MVVM. I hope these will help you.

Answer (score 2):

A great list of MVVM frameworks can be found at [MVVM Framework Explorer](http://www.japf.fr/silverlight/mvvm/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

[MVVM Light](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsTemplateStudio/issues/3753) and [Caliburn](https://caliburnmicro.com/announcements/) are no longer supported, but there is a new player on the market

- [Microsoft MVVM Toolkit](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-ch/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/introduction) which ist part of the [Windows Community Toolkit](https://github.com/windows-toolkit). It contains the usual support for MVVM and a very fast messaging system.